# Using String Space

Tags: java

I build simple code for checking equal String, but if I using space in content of String A and content of String B same with String A "using space" the result will be "false".

this may code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String A = "I write code";
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Words : ");
        String B = input.next();
        if(A.contentEquals(B)) {
            System.out.println("True");
        } else {
            System.out.println("False");
        }
    }
```

but if I change content of String A without space and content String B same with content of String A the result will be "true" .

My question is how to make the result "True" if String A using space ?

Comment: What do you mean by *"using space"*? Provide an example.

Comment: if(a.trim().equals(b.trim()))

Comment: And btw, you can simply do `System.out.println(A.contentEquals(B));`

Comment: Thanks all it's so helpful

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
String B = input.next();
```

stops reading the input when it encounters a space. If you want to be able to input an entire sentence, use [`nextLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29).

Answer (score 0):

Use `trim()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String A = "I write code";
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter Words : ");
    String B = input.next().trim();
    if(a.contentEquals(b)){
        System.out.println("True");
    }else
        System.out.println("False");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying using as below ( assuming you have created contentEquals(..) method and having null checks)

```
     if(a.trim().contentEquals(b.trim())){
        System.out.println("True");
    }else
        System.out.println("False");
```

Not sure about the contents of contentEquals(..) method, if you are just checking equals, use as below

```
    if(a.trim().equals(b.trim())){
        System.out.println("True");
    }else
        System.out.println("False");
```

Answer (score 0):

you will get a compilation error first of all for using

```
a.contentEquals(b)
```

as `a` and `b` are not defined

first use

```
A.contentEquals(B)
```

and the rest of code

```
String A = "I write code";
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter Words : ");
String B = input.nextLine();
if(A.contentEquals(B)){
    System.out.println("True");
}else
   System.out.println("False");
```

`input.next()` terminates as soon as we enter `space bar`..so we have to use `input.nextLine()`